# React native typescript how to type FlatList

Tags: typescript, react-native

I don't find the way to type a FlatList in react native

```
export interface Category {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  bg: string;
}
export const CATEGORIES: Category[] = [
  { id: "c1", title: "Italian", bg: "#f5428d" }
];


const Item = ({ data }: { data: Category }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{data.title}</Text>
  </View>
);
const CategoriesScreen = ({ navigation }: CategoriesScreenProps) => {
  const renderItem  = ({
    data,
  }: {
    data: Category;
  }) => <Item data={data} />;
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={CATEGORIES}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      numColumns={2}
    ></FlatList>
  );
};
```

I've got this error in  renderItem props:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props:
> FlatListProps | Readonly<FlatListProps>):
> FlatList', gave the following error.
> Type '({ data, }: { data: Category; }) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ListRenderItem'.
> Types of parameters '__0' and 'info' are incompatible.
> Property 'data' is missing in type 'ListRenderItemInfo' but required in type '{ data: Category;
> }'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: FlatListProps, context:
> any): FlatList', gave the following error.
> Type '({ data, }: { data: Category; }) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ListRenderItem

What's wrong, please?

Comment: Change `data` with `item`

Answer (score 9):

I know this is super old, but I think I might have the solution that you were ultimately looking for. I think we must be walking through the same tutorial, because I ran into this exact same problem with the exact same typing issue.

If I'm understanding this correctly, ultimately what everyone else has said here is technically correct; the data that's used by the `FlatList` is  going to be a `ListRenderItem<T>`. However, the individual data items wrapped by `ListRenderItem` that are passed to the function you define for the `renderItem` prop is actually of type `ListRenderItemInfo<T>`. So, you should be able to type your function parameters like I've typed the `itemData` parameter below:

```
import { FlatList, ListRenderItemInfo } from "react-native"
import { CategoryGridTile } from "irrelevant"
import { CATEGORIES } from "irrelevant"
import Category from "irrelevant"

export const CategoriesScreen: React.FC = () => {
    return <FlatList
        data={CATEGORIES}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={renderCategoryItem}
    />
}

const renderCategoryItem = (itemData: ListRenderItemInfo<Category>) => {
    return <CategoryGridTile title={itemData.item.title} color={itemData.item.color} />
}
```

Where `Category` is:

```
class Category {
  constructor(id, title, color) {
    this.id = id
    this.title = title
    this.color = color
  }
}
```

I found this by digging into the definition of `FlatList` and its types:

```
export interface ListRenderItemInfo<ItemT> {
    item: ItemT;

    index: number;

    separators: {
        highlight: () => void;
        unhighlight: () => void;
        updateProps: (select: 'leading' | 'trailing', newProps: any) => void;
    };
}

export type ListRenderItem<ItemT> = (info: ListRenderItemInfo<ItemT>) => React.ReactElement | null;
```

I'm sure you've long passed this issue, but hopefully it helps someone else dealing with the same typing problem.

Comment: Have been looking for this for a while, the ListRenderItemInfo<T> did the trick

Answer (score 2):

renderItem has the interface ListRenderItem< ItemT > , so the "data" param doesn't exist, because ListRenderItem only knows "item", "index" and "separator". Try to replace its ItemT with your data.

How do you do that?
It's simple:

1st - import the ListRenderItem interface from react-native,

```
import { ListRenderItem } from 'react-native';
```

2nd - type the constant receiving the renderItem function instead of the params, replacing its "ItemT" with your item interface:

```
const renderItem: ListRenderItem<Category> = ({ item }) => (
   <Item data={item} />
)
```

That's it!! Wanna check it out the code? here it is: [expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/DJTxOuocm)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but now I've got this error  Type '({ data, }: { data: Category; }) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ListRenderItem<Category>'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'info' are incompatible.
    Property 'data' is missing in type 'ListRenderItemInfo<Category>' but required in type '{ data: Category; }'.ts(2322)

Answer (score 2):

I think here the error desribes what went wrond :"  Property 'data' is missing in type 'ListRenderItemInfo' but required in type '{ data: Category; }'."

```
  const renderItem  = ({data}: {data: Category}) => <Item data={data} />
```

You need to pass an object which has a "data" property, but you did not.

```
 <FlatList
  data={CATEGORIES}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  renderItem= {renderItem} // {(receivesArg)=>renderItem(passArg)}
  numColumns={2}
></FlatList>
```

or

```
<FlatList
      data={CATEGORIES}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      // import {ReactElement} from "react"
      renderItem= {({ data }:data: Category;}):ReactElement => <Item data={data} />}
      numColumns={2}
    ></FlatList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write like this:

```
<FlatList<Category>
      data={CATEGORIES}
      .....
```

Answer (score 0):

The flatList component passes each item in your array as a variable with the name `item` to the `renderItem` prop. So you need to replace `data` with `item`, like this:

```
const renderItem  = ({item}: {item: Category}) => <Item data={item} />;

<FlatList
    data={CATEGORIES}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    numColumns={2}
></FlatList>
```